# SQL concatenate many tsv files into single table in a database, while keeping track of file source (MonetDBLite)

Tags: sql, r, monetdb, monetdblite

I am using the MonetDBLite R package to create a MonetDB. I can create database tables just fine using the instructions from [here](https://github.com/hannesmuehleisen/MonetDBLite), with the following code:

```
library(DBI)
library(MonetDBLite)

# Write tsv file of mtcars
write.table(mtcars, "mtcars.tsv", row.names=FALSE, sep= "\t")

# Initialize MonetDB
dbdir <- "/Users/admin/my_directory"
con <- dbConnect(MonetDBLite::MonetDBLite(), dbdir)

# Write table
dbWriteTable(con, "test4", "mtcars.tsv", delim="\t")
```

and the following query gives

```
> dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT * FROM test4 LIMIT 3")
mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
1  21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
2  21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
3  22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
```

So far so good. But, say I have another file mtcars2 with different mpg values:

```
mtcars2 <- mtcars
mtcars2$mpg <- mtcars2$mpg + 5
write.table(mtcars2, "mtcars2.tsv", row.names= FALSE, sep = "\t")
```

I can load it to another table:

```
dbWriteTable(con, "test5", "mtcars2.tsv", delim = "\t")
> dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT * FROM test5 LIMIT 3")
mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
1 26.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
2 26.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
3 27.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
```

Also fine. But my problem is this: I want to later on look up the `mpg` for all cars with 6 `cyl`, and know which dataset it came from (mtcars or mtcars2). From what I understand of SQL indexing (which is not a lot and basically what I've read [here](http://www.sqlite.org/queryplanner.html)), I should have all my data in one table to have the most efficient searches. I tried loading the first tsv file, then added another column using `ALTER TABLE test4 ADD dataset TEXT` and `UPDATE test4 SET dataset = dataset1` sql commands-

```
dbSendQuery(con, "UPDATE test4 SET dataset = dataset1")
dbSendQuery(con, "UPDATE test4 SET dataset = 1")
> dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT * FROM test4 LIMIT 3")
mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb dataset
1 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4       1
2 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4       1
3 22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1       1
```

but then when I tried to append mtcars2 to the table, it had a different number of columns (as I should have expected, duh). What's the best way to concatenate data from many tsv files with identical columns into a single table, while keeping track of the data's source?

EDIT- as you might have guessed, the real data is not mtcars- it's flat tsv files millions of lines long, meaning I want to avoid reading the whole file into memory and manipulating with R.

Comment: Logical process: After importing both datasets, alter each table to define a `source` field.  Then update the field to the desired  value for all records in both tables.  Then select from one table inserting into the second table all the desired records.  then drop the 2nd unneeded/merged table.  Alternatively write a view which unions the two tables and adds a the column; but it will not be as efficient as you already noted..

Comment: Great! That makes sense- I'll post the code if I can manage to get it working this way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following [xQbert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1016435/xqbert)'s suggestion, I solved using SQL commands only (necessary and faster than bash commands, considering my data is 10s of files, each millions of lines long).

```
library(DBI)
library(MonetDBLite)

# Write tsv file of mtcars
write.table(mtcars, "mtcars.tsv", row.names=FALSE, sep= "\t")

# Write tsv of second mtcars
mtcars2 <- mtcars
mtcars2$mpg <- mtcars2$mpg + 5
write.table(mtcars2, "mtcars2.tsv", row.names= FALSE, sep = "\t")

# Initialize MonetDB
dbdir <- "/Users/admin/"
con <- dbConnect(MonetDBLite::MonetDBLite(), dbdir)

# Write table
dbWriteTable(con, "test4", "mtcars.tsv", delim="\t")

# Add data source information
dbSendQuery(con, "ALTER TABLE test4 ADD source TEXT")
dbSendQuery(con, "UPDATE test4 SET source = 'dataset1'")

# Write second dataset to a temporary table
dbWriteTable(con, "temptable", "mtcars2.tsv", delim="\t")

# Add data source information
dbSendQuery(con, "ALTER TABLE temptable ADD source TEXT")
dbSendQuery(con, "UPDATE temptable SET source = 'dataset2'")

# Insert temp table into main table
dbSendQuery(con, "INSERT INTO test4 SELECT * FROM temptable")

# Drop temp table
dbSendQuery(con, "DROP TABLE temptable")

# Checking the data, truncated for clarity
> dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT * FROM test4")
mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb   source
1  21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4 dataset1
2  21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4 dataset1
3  22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1 dataset1
...
33 26.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4 dataset2
34 26.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4 dataset2
35 27.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1 dataset2
...
64 26.4   4 121.0 109 4.11 2.780 18.60  1  1    4    2 dataset2
```

Sorry if I didn't make it clear enough in the question that my data is much larger than mtcars- if you have medium sized data, the `data.tables` package is probably a better solution than a database.

Comment: Yup! It took about 15 min to process 32 files, 4.9 million lines long with 11 columns. Which probably as good as I'm going to get in an R framework. Thanks!

Comment: Excellent.  Be sure to accept your answer! :P  I'd named the sources the file names but that's me... or maybe you wanted obfuscation.

Comment: Aha it's unpublished data, and I'm probably too paranoid, but one doesn't want to get scooped in research. Stack Overflow says I need to wait until tomorrow to accept my own answer, but I'll be sure to do it then.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do what you want with executing `dbWriteTable()` after reading the file create a new variable in the data.frame. Something like:

```
  library(DBI)
  library(MonetDBLite)
  library(data.table)

  # Write tsv file of mtcars
  tmp <- tempfile()
  write.table(mtcars, tmp, row.names=FALSE, sep= "\t")

  # Initialize MonetDB
  dbdir <- "~/Desktop/temp"
  con <- dbConnect(MonetDBLite::MonetDBLite(), dbdir)

  test4df <- fread(tmp)
  test4df$dataset <- 1
  dbWriteTable(con, "test4", test4df)

  dbReadTable(con, "test4")

  test5df <- fread(tmp)
  test5df$mpg <- test5df$mpg + 5
  test5df$dataset <- 2
  dbWriteTable(con, "test4", test5df, append = TRUE)

  dbReadTable(con, "test4")
```

**Edit (Suggestion on the way without opening the file)**

If you want to the work without opening a file in one time, you can do something like this to modify the file and attach another field. As I wrote this will work with an OS with `bash`.

```
infile <- tmp
outfile <- tempfile()

# open connections
incon <- file(description = infile, open = "r")
outcon <- file(description = outfile, open = "w")

# count the number of lines (this will work only with Mac/Linux)
com <- paste("wc -l ", infile, " | awk '{ print $1 }'", sep="")
n <- system(command=com, intern=TRUE)

# work with the first line
txt <- scan(file = incon, what = character(), nlines=1, quiet=TRUE)
txt <- c(txt, "dataset")
cat(paste(txt, collapse = "\t"), "\n", file = outcon, sep = "")

# work with the rest of the file
for(i in 2:n) {
  txt <- scan(file = incon, what = character(), nlines=1, quiet=TRUE)
  txt <- c(txt, "1")
  cat(paste(txt, collapse = "\t"), "\n", file = outcon, sep = "")
}
close(incon);close(outcon)
dbWriteTable(con, "test4", outfile, delim = "\t")
# do the similar for other files
```

Comment: Yes, for mtcars sized data this is the best solution (if you for some reason needed to make it a database). But my real data is not mtcars sized- it's text files millions of lines long, meaning we want to avoid if all possible reading the whole file into memory.

Comment: I edited my answer. First of all, I would try with `fread` in `data.table` which will be more memory efficient. If this doesn't work, I'd try the second possible solution.

Comment: Unfortunately we are going the `MonetDBlite` route because `fread` is too slow for the amount and size of files we're analyzing. Thanks for the suggestion though, the `data.tables` package is really great for data of a certain size.

Comment: Please read my comment/answer carefully. As I said in the previous comment, the suggestion I show in the edited answer does not rely on `data.table` and write a table in database without opening the file.

Comment: Yes, I see also that you use bash commands in the edited comment. For the reason that we want to write this into a code that works cross-platform, using SQL commands is better than using bash commands for our usage. From what I understand, it's also slower than using SQL commands, but I might be wrong on that.

Comment: You are probably right about the performance of my suggestion as it will write a file.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I would do, given a set of files with the same structure and file names desired in the final table, which is otherwise a combination of the data from all files:

```
# say we have those files
write.table(mtcars, "mtcars1.tsv", row.names=FALSE, sep= "\t")
write.table(mtcars, "mtcars2.tsv", row.names=FALSE, sep= "\t")

# write them individually, and add a column that contains the file name
dbWriteTable(con, "mtcars1", "mtcars1.tsv", delim="\t")
dbSendQuery(con, "ALTER TABLE mtcars1 ADD COLUMN file STRING DEFAULT 'mtcars1.tsv';")
dbWriteTable(con, "mtcars2", "mtcars2.tsv", delim="\t")
dbSendQuery(con, "ALTER TABLE mtcars2 ADD COLUMN file STRING DEFAULT 'mtcars2.tsv';")

# now combine into a new table
dbSendQuery(con, "CREATE TABLE mtcars_mat AS SELECT * FROM mtcars1 UNION ALL SELECT * FROM mtcars2")

# or a view if you don't need to modify the data in the mtcars table (faster)
dbSendQuery(con, "CREATE view mtcars AS SELECT * FROM mtcars1 UNION ALL SELECT * FROM mtcars2")



# and here is the same as a loop with a filename glob and some added robustness (handy if you have 1000 files)
files <- Sys.glob("/some/path/mtcars*.tsv")
tables <- dbQuoteIdentifier(con, tools::file_path_sans_ext(basename(files)))
dbBegin(con)
for (i in 1:length(files)) {
  dbWriteTable(con, tables[i], files[i], delim="\t", transaction=FALSE)
  dbSendQuery(con, paste0("ALTER TABLE ", tables[i], " ADD COLUMN file STRING DEFAULT ",dbQuoteString(con, files[i]),";"))
}
dbSendQuery(con, paste0("CREATE TABLE somefinalresult AS ", paste0("SELECT * FROM ",tables, collapse=" UNION ALL ")))
# remove the parts again, optional
dbSendQuery(con, paste0("DROP TABLE ", tables, ";", collapse=" "))
dbCommit(con)
```